# Anki build fails with "protoc_wrapper failed"

Tags: python, build, bazel, anki

I'm on an arch linux machine and trying to compile anki from source, despite following the [instructions](https://github.com/ankitects/anki/blob/main/docs/linux.md), I seem to get the following error no matter what I do:

```
ERROR: /home/b3nj4m1n/Documents/Github/anki/pylib/anki/BUILD.bazel:111:9: Action pylib/anki/backend_pb2.py failed: (Exit 1): protoc_wrapper failed: error executing command bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/pylib/tools/protoc_wrapper external/protoc_bin_linux_x86_64/bin/protoc bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/pylib/tools/protoc-gen-mypy ... (remaining 20 arguments skipped)

Use --sandbox_debug to see verbose messages from the sandbox
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/b3nj4m1n/.cache/bazel/_bazel_b3nj4m1n/ee6625df9ac32592700069683600f2ec/sandbox/linux-sandbox/288/execroot/ankidesktop/bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/pylib/tools/protoc_wrapper.runfiles/ankidesktop/pylib/tools/protoc_wrapper.py", line 23, in <module>
    subprocess.run(
  File "/home/b3nj4m1n/.cache/bazel/_bazel_b3nj4m1n/ee6625df9ac32592700069683600f2ec/external/python/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 528, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['external/protoc_bin_linux_x86_64/bin/protoc', '--plugin=protoc-gen-mypy=bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/pylib/tools/protoc-gen-mypy', '--python_out=bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/pylib', '--mypy_out=bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/pylib', '-Iproto/', '-Iexternal/ankidesktop/proto/', 'proto/anki/backend.proto', 'proto/anki/card_rendering.proto', 'proto/anki/cards.proto', 'proto/anki/collection.proto', 'proto/anki/config.proto', 'proto/anki/deckconfig.proto', 'proto/anki/decks.proto', 'proto/anki/generic.proto', 'proto/anki/i18n.proto', 'proto/anki/import_export.proto', 'proto/anki/links.proto', 'proto/anki/media.proto', 'proto/anki/notes.proto', 'proto/anki/notetypes.proto', 'proto/anki/scheduler.proto', 'proto/anki/search.proto', 'proto/anki/stats.proto', 'proto/anki/sync.proto', 'proto/anki/tags.proto']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
Target //qt:runanki failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
ERROR: /home/b3nj4m1n/Documents/Github/anki/qt/BUILD.bazel:123:10 Middleman _middlemen/qt_Srunanki-runfiles failed: (Exit 1): protoc_wrapper failed: error executing command bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/pylib/tools/protoc_wrapper external/protoc_bin_linux_x86_64/bin/protoc bazel-out/k8-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6/bin/pylib/tools/protoc-gen-mypy ... (remaining 20 arguments skipped)
```

Just for testing purposes, I wrote a dockerfile which tries to build anki in an isolated environment. This works without issues. ([Here](https://pastebin.com/9xX5TYZC)'s the dockerfile)

I verified that I have all the dependencies from the dockerfile installed on my main machine, but I still get the same error.

I also tried clearing the bazel cache without any success.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm if you have followed these steps

1. Install Xubuntu (xubuntu-20.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso) into a new VM.
2. Install VirtualBox Guest Additions and the automatic Xubuntu updates.
3. Install these packages and bazel according to linux.md.

Kindly refer to this [document](https://forums.ankiweb.net/t/guide-how-to-build-and-run-anki-from-source-with-xubuntu-20-04/12865) on how to build Anki from source.Thank you!